# Query Parameters In Jersey

Tags: java, jersey

I have a question about the query parameter.. 
What is the idea of that parameter.. 
In the case from below for what i need the query parameter ?

```
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public String sayHello(@QueryParam("name") String name) {
    if (name != null) {
        // if the query parameter "name" is there
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

Comment: not sure I understand.. the query parameters contains a value you are passing to the server when invoking the GET request (in this case) - the server would determine what to do with such parameter (is that what you are asking?)

Comment: What is the difference between QueryParam and Param ?

Comment: where is param? - the query param is the param in the query string (i.e. at the end of your URL)

Comment: I've seen QueryParam and PathParam - where do you find Param?

Comment: I mean Jersey API has annotations PathParam and QueryParam.. 
What is the difference between  them ?

Comment: path param is found on the path of the request, i.e. `/my/url/{my_path_param}/sayHello` - typically you want to use one or the other (I don't recall having to use both) - the query param is at the end i.e. `/my/url/echo/sayHello?query_param=world`

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand this.. What do you mean by "Found on the path".. ? QueryParam and PathParam as i know mapped both to the parameter in the method.. Can you give me example or link to more concretized explanation ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@PathParam is used when you have a service that is defined like:

```
@POST
@Path("/update/{userCode}")
public Response update(@PathParam( "userCode" ) String userCode)
```

in this example, the URL would be something like http://hostname.tld/update/1234 where the "1234" would be parsed out of the path portion of the URL.

@QueryParam is when your URL includes normal URL parameters like @Partha suggests:

```
@POST
@Path("/update")
public Response update(@QueryParam( "userCode" ) String userCode)
```

here the URL would look like http://hostname.tld/update?userCode=1234

Which one you use depends on the style you'd like.  REST aficionados would tell you that you should never use the QueryParam version.  I'm a bit more flexible - the advantage of the QueryParam version is that you are not locked into an ordering, just names.

But it is ultimately up to you which makes more sense for your application.

Comment: So as i understand from your example: the difference is in the URL representation ? With QueryParam i can see the name and the value.. 
With PathParam i can see only the value ?

Comment: In effect, yes.  QueryParam is the "old" way of doing it.  If you had a bunch of parameters it would be http://somehost.tld/?paramA=hello&paramB=there&paramC=all as an example.  PathParam is order dependent - there needs to be documentation that tells the user what order the parameters go in as they are not self documenting.

Comment: public Response update(@PathParam( "userCode" ) String userCode)
From your example.. the PathParam and the parameter always has to be with the same name?

Comment: No, in the PathParam version it could be anything - the JAX-RS (Jersey) engine just matches the annotation part (the @Path) with the order of the parameters.  So with two params it might be @Path("/update/{userCode}/{phone}") with the @PathParam part being update(@PathParam( "userCode" ) String userCode, @PathParam("phone") String whatever).

Answer (score 0):

So if your REST url is http://somecompany.com/api/user?name=Maks you can process that information here and use that name in whatever you want to do in the method you have written.